# Python (2.7) Operation on a closed file error

Tags: python

Another user here recently helped me refine the code below.  I have the sorted list of the integers, but I don't know how to get the original list since the with statement closes the file it is reading from.  I have already returned the variable "List" and have a print statement for it, if I can just find a way to produce it.  I thought it would be easy enough to use the readlines fuction, but I can't figure out how to do that.  Thanks for any help!  I am still new to Python...

```
import random
with open("1000.txt", "w") as f:
    for x in range(1000):
        f.write(str(random.randint(0, 9999))+"\n")

def readList():
    infile = raw_input("Input File Name: ")
    rawList = list()    
    with open(infile, 'r') as infi:
        for line in infi:
            rawList.append(int(line))
    sortedList = sortList(rawList) #function call for sorting the list, returned sorted list is stored
    n = int(raw_input("Which number do you want to return?: "))
    user_num = int(float(n-1))
    return sortedList, user_num, List

def sortList(inpList): #function needs list as input and returns sorted list
    inpList.sort() 
    return inpList

if __name__=='__main__': #This is how the main is defined in python
    sortedList, List, user_num = readList() #function call of readList, returned two objects are stored in variables
    first = sortedList[0] 
    lines = len(sortedList)
    orig_min_val = min(List)
    orig_max_val = max(List)
    minimum_val = min(sortedList)
    maximum_val = max(sortedList)
    if user_num > 1000:
        print user_num, "is greater than 1000!" # you don't need brackets when printing
    elif user_num > lines:
        print "There aren't that many numbers in the list!"
    elif lines < 1000:
        print "WARNING: only", lines, "numbers were read into the list!"
    print "Before sort:"
    print "Min is", orig_min_val
    print "Max is", orig_max_val
    print "After sort:"
    print "Min is", minimum_val
    print "Max is", maximum_val
    print user_num
```

Comment: *"I have already returned the variable "List" and have a print statement for it, if I can just find a way to produce it."* What do you mean exactly? You call `readList()` from `main()` -> you're prompted for a filename -> the file is read, converted to list and sorted -> `sortedList, List, user_num` is returned and can now be accessed from `main()` (although the order of the variables is messed up). I didn't read the code closely but what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Spelling and ordering are VERY important in programming. You have a couple small blunders.

First, this line:

```
return sortedList, user_num, List
```

Is returning something called `List`. However, you don't actually have a variable called `List` anywhere in that method; what you're actually returning is a reference to the python class `List` (Notice how the syntax highlighting in your post colors it blue? That's why). You probably want to instead return `rawList` like this:

```
return sortedList, user_num, rawList
```

Second, this line:

```
sortedList, List, user_num = readList()
```

Is getting the results back from that return. If you look closely, you'll see that they're actually in the wrong order. Not only that, but you are assigning one of the values to the python class `List`! This is very bad. I recommend you rename your variable in the `__main__` method from `List` to `rawList`, and make sure your variables are correctly ordered like so:

```
sortedList, user_num, rawList = readList()
```